# Modify animated CSS background-image with opacity slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to control the opacity of the animated CSS background-image from my first code snippet. Therefore I want to use a slider as seen in my second code snippet.
This is just one example, but I'm often in the situation that I don't know how to take an already existing image and use it for another operation. What can I do in such a case?

```css
.page-header:after {
  animation: img1 .85s infinite linear;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/LZJVN0S.png);
  content: "";
  z-index: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 300%;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -110%;
  width: 300%;
}

@keyframes img1 {
  0% {
    background-position: top 150px left 120px, 110px 90px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: top 150px left 100px, 362px 90px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top 150px left 120px, 615px 90px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"></div>
```

```js
var rangeVal = document.getElementById('rangevalue');
var range = document.getElementById('range');
var updateVal = function(val) {
  rangeVal.innerHTML = val;
  rangeVal.style.left = val + '%';
};
updateVal(range.value);

var imgP = document.getElementsByClassName("imgP")[0];
range.addEventListener("input", function(value) {
  imgP.style.opacity = this.value / this.max;
});
```

```css
.imgP {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="range" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:20px">
  <input type="range" id="range" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="updateVal(this.value)" style="position:fixed; top:32px; left:8px">
  <div id="rangevalue" class="range-thumb"></div>
  <img class="imgP" height="imageheight" width="imagewidth" src='https://png.icons8.com/nolan/50/000000/percentage.png' style="position:fixed; top:56px; left:18px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.imgP` to `.page-header` in the HTML (or replace `imgP` with `page-hader` in the JavaScript.)

```js
var rangeVal = document.getElementById('rangevalue');
var range = document.getElementById('range');
var updateVal = function(val) {
  rangeVal.innerHTML = val;
  rangeVal.style.left = val + '%';
};
updateVal(range.value);

var imgP = document.getElementsByClassName("imgP")[0];
range.addEventListener("input", function(value) {
  imgP.style.opacity = this.value / this.max;
});
```

```css
.imgP {
  opacity: 1;
}

.page-header:after {
  animation: img1 .85s infinite linear;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/LZJVN0S.png);
  content: "";
  z-index: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 300%;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -110%;
  width: 300%;
}

@keyframes img1 {
  0% {
    background-position: top 150px left 120px, 110px 90px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: top 150px left 100px, 362px 90px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top 150px left 120px, 615px 90px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header imgP"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"></div>

<div class="range" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:20px">
  <input type="range" id="range" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="updateVal(this.value)" style="position:fixed; top:32px; left:8px">
  <div id="rangevalue" class="range-thumb"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rangeVal = document.getElementById('rangevalue');
var range = document.getElementById('range');
var updateVal = function(val) {
  rangeVal.innerHTML = val;
    rangeVal.style.left = val + '%';
};
updateVal(range.value);

var imgP = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header")[0];
range.addEventListener("input", function(value) {
    imgP.style.opacity = this.value / this.max;
});
```

```css
.page-header:after {
  animation:img1 .85s infinite linear;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/LZJVN0S.png);
  content: ""; z-index:100; pointer-events:none; height:300%;
  left:-50%; opacity:1; position:fixed; top: -110%; width: 300%;
  opacity:1;
}
@keyframes img1 {
  0% {background-position: top 150px left 120px, 110px 90px;}
  50% {background-position: top 150px left 100px, 362px 90px;}
  100% {background-position: top 150px left 120px, 615px 90px;}
```

```html
<div class="range"
     style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:20px;bottom:20">
<input type="range" id="range" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="updateVal(this.value)"
     style="position:fixed; top:32px; left:8px">
<div id="rangevalue" class="range-thumb"></div>
<div class="page-header"></div> 
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"></div>
```

Comment: Tell me for more help